# How to use classes from mobile module?

Tags: android, gradle, wear-os

Some time ago i created a wear module on existing project.
Both modules have identical Application ID and packages.

Is there any possibility to solve this problem without creating new Android Library to contain classes which i want to be shared? (I have too many files and it will take too much time to fix project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afraid not (there is no "possibility... without creating new Android Library"). The handheld and wearable apps are distinct APKs, running on separate devices, and cannot share code at runtime. You need to move your common code into a library that will be compiled into into both.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
That's pity. So i'll have to waste more time to do it :)

Comment: It's not a waste if it's a necessary step in extending your app to a new class of device. :^)

Comment: It's my sense of humor :)